# How to get taxonomy terms by using their ID's in a specific order

Tags: php, wordpress, taxonomy

I am trying to get my taxonomy terms by using their ID's but I want to  order my ID's in a specific order and not just ASC

```
$taxonomy = 'menu-food-categories';
$taxonomy_terms = get_terms( $taxonomy, 'orderby=ID&order=ASC&parent=0' );
```

Something like:

```
$args_terms = array(
                       'post_in' => array(49,5,12,80),
                       'orderby' => post_in,
                       'parent' => '0'
                   );

          $taxonomy = 'menu-food-categories';
          $taxonomy_terms = get_terms($taxonomy, $args_terms);
```

Comment: How long is the list?  Couldn't you just get the array unsorted from the database, and then manually sort it yourself?

Comment: The list is only 6-7 ID's so yeah I could absolutely do it that way. I just figured there was a way to do it using wordpress's core functions. Thanks for the idea. +1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do this by

```
// Get term by id (''term_id'') in Categories taxonomy.
get_term_by('id', 12, 'category')
```

[as per this link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_by)

go through below code for more information ::

```
$taxonomy = 'menu-food-categories';
$args_terms_id_list = array(49,5,12,80);

foreach ($args_terms_id_list as $current_term_id){
    // Get term by id (''term_id'') in Categories taxonomy.
$taxonomy_terms = get_term_by('id', $current_term_id , $taxonomy)
// Do your code here
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Since 4.5.0, taxonomies should be passed via the ‘taxonomy’ argument in the $args array:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_term_query/__construct/

The values you can use
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_term_query/__construct/#source

```
$myterms = get_terms( array(
              'taxonomy' => 'menu-food-categories',
              'hide_empty' => false,
              'include' => array(49,5,12,80)
            ));
```

Print name

```
foreach ($myterms as $key => $value) {
              echo $value->name;
}
```